how to convert arrays to use with fprintf and fgets
I'm trying to make a simple program that stores, and loads text, so I can later display it via a notification with a mere press off three buttons, however I'm running into the problem of fprintf and fgets not being able to use arrays, could anyone suggest  a better way of saving and loading, I'm really new to programming in the c language so any advice would be greatly appreciated
code and errors below
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<stdbool.h>
#include<stdint.h>
#include<string.h>
#include <readline/readline.h>
#include <readline/history.h>
#include<signal.h>
#include <libnotify/notify.h>
#define EXIT_SUCCES 0
#define EXIT_FALIURE_READING_FILE 1
#define EXIT_FALIURE_LIBNOTIFY 2
char *ProgramTitle = "styckynotes";
char *messages_array[9] = {"this mesage has not yet been set","this mesage has not yet been set","this mesage has not yet been set","this mesage has not yet been set","this mesage has not yet been set","this mesage has not yet been set","this mesage has not yet been set","this mesage has not yet been set","this mesage has not yet been set"};
int change_messgages(int array_number,char* new_message){
    if (array_number > 10){
        fprintf(stderr,"you are trying to write to a array number that doesnt exist, this would corrupt the memory please do not do that");
    }
    if (sizeof(new_message)>100){
        fprintf(stderr,"message too long try keeping it under 100 charachters");
    }
    if ((array_number < 10) && (sizeof(new_message)<100)){
    free(messages_array[array_number]);
    messages_array[array_number] = malloc(strlen(new_message) + 1);
    messages_array[array_number-1] = new_message;
    strcpy(messages_array[array_number], new_message);
    FILE *myFile = fopen("messages.txt", "w");
    int i;
    if (myFile == NULL){
        printf("Error Reading File\n");
        exit(EXIT_FALIURE_READING_FILE);
    }
    for (i = 0; i < 8; i++){
        fprintf(myFile, &messages_array[i]);
    }
        fclose(myFile);
    }
    return 0;
    }
int note_pls(int count, int key){
    printf("%d", count);
    printf("%d", count);

    int pull_from=key-1;
    NotifyNotification *notification = notify_notification_new("reminder", messages_array[pull_from], "dialog-information");
    if (notification == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Got a null notify handle!\n");
    }
    notify_notification_show (notification, NULL);
    g_object_unref(G_OBJECT(notification));
    notify_uninit();
    return 0;
}
int signal_handler(void){
    //im counting from one since thats how an avarge user would experience it
    rl_command_func_t  note_pls;
    rl_command_func_t  exitrl;
    rl_bind_keyseq("\\C-e-1",note_pls);
    rl_bind_keyseq("\\C-e-2",note_pls);
    rl_bind_keyseq("\\C-e-3",note_pls);
    rl_bind_keyseq("\\C-e-4",note_pls);
    rl_bind_keyseq("\\C-e-5",note_pls);
    rl_bind_keyseq("\\C-e-6",note_pls);
    rl_bind_keyseq("\\C-e-7",note_pls);
    rl_bind_keyseq("\\C-e-8",note_pls);
    rl_bind_keyseq("\\C-e-9",note_pls);
    rl_bind_keyseq("\\C-e-0",exitrl);
    return 0;
}
int exitrl(int count, int key){
    exit(EXIT_SUCCES);
}
int main(void){
    bool notifyInitStatus = notify_init(ProgramTitle);
    if (!notifyInitStatus) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error initialising with libnotify!\n");
        exit(EXIT_FALIURE_LIBNOTIFY);
    FILE *myFile = fopen("messages.txt", "r");
    int i;
    if (myFile == NULL){
        printf("Error Reading File\n");
        exit (EXIT_FALIURE_READING_FILE);
    }
    for (i = 0; i < 8; i++){
        fgets(&messages_array[i],100,myFile);
    }
        fclose(myFile);
    }
    signal_handler(); // for readability
}

tickynotes.c: In function ‘change_messgages’:
stickynotes.c:35:25: warning: passing argument 2 of ‘fprintf’ from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
   35 |         fprintf(myFile, &messages_array[i]);
      |                         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      |                         |
      |                         char **
In file included from stickynotes.c:1:
/usr/include/stdio.h:358:44: note: expected ‘const char * restrict’ but argument is of type ‘char **’
  358 |                     const char *__restrict __format, ...) __nonnull ((1));
      |                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~
stickynotes.c:35:25: warning: format not a string literal and no format arguments [-Wformat-security]
   35 |         fprintf(myFile, &messages_array[i]);
      |                         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
stickynotes.c: In function ‘main’:
stickynotes.c:86:15: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘fgets’ from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
   86 |         fgets(&messages_array[i],100,myFile);
      |               ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      |               |
      |               char **
/usr/include/stdio.h:654:38: note: expected ‘char * restrict’ but argument is of type ‘char **’
  654 | extern char *fgets (char *__restrict __s, int __n, FILE *__restrict __stream)
      |                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~
/usr/bin/ld: cannot open output file build/stickynotesd: No such file or directory
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [makefile:6: stickynotes] Error 1


Please try to make the program simpler, much simpler, into a [mre].

There are also plenty of other problems in the code you show. Like using sizeof on a pointer, loosing pointers returned by malloc; Or potentially going out of bounds of arrays; Using user-input as format strings in a printf call; And inconsistent or missing indentation making the code much harder to read than it needs to be. All in all I think you're not really ready for this kind of code, and that you need to go back and study more of the basics.

The error messages are rather clear in the fact that you are passing a wrong level of indirection. A pointer to a pointer is not the same as an array. It is strange that in one line strcpy(messages_array[array_number] you know how to use that pointer and in another line fprintf(myFile, &messages_array[i]); you forgot how to use it. Both functions require a char* but one time you use & and the other time you don't. Why are you so inconsistent with your pointers?

free(messages_array[array_number]); You initialize that array with pointers to string literals. You cannot free a string literal. You can only free memory you retrieved via malloc or similar function.

This message:
stickynotes.c:35:25: warning: passing argument 2 of ‘fprintf’ from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
   35 |         fprintf(myFile, &messages_array[i]);
      |                         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      |                         |
      |                         char **
In file included from stickynotes.c:1:
/usr/include/stdio.h:358:44: note: expected ‘const char * restrict’ but argument is of type ‘char **’
  358 |                     const char *__restrict __format, ...) __nonnull ((1));
      |                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~

tells the problem.
Here:
stickynotes.c:35:25: warning: passing argument 2 of ‘fprintf’ from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
   35 |         fprintf(myFile, &messages_array[i]);
      |                         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      |                         |
      |                         char **

The problem is described: "... incompatible pointer type"
It also tells you the problematic line. It even tells you where in the line using the ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ underscope-like notation. And further it tells you that &messages_array[i] has the type char **.
So it boils down to that you are passing a char ** to fprintf but fprintf doesn't expect a char**.
So what does fprintf expect?
Well, that is actually in the following message:
In file included from stickynotes.c:1:
/usr/include/stdio.h:358:44: note: expected ‘const char * restrict’ but argument is of type ‘char **’
  358 |                     const char *__restrict __format, ...) __nonnull ((1));
      |                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~

It tells you "expected ‘const char * restrict’ but argument is of type ‘char **’"
So that's it:
fprintf wants a char* but you give it a char** because you do: &messages_array[i]
The definition of messages_array is:
char *messages_array[9] = ....

So messages_array is an array of char* with 9 elements.
Consequently, messages_array[i] will give you the type char* while &messages_array[i] will give you the type char**.
In other words - messages_array[i] already has the type expected by fprintf but you change that using &. The solution is simply to remove the & when calling fprintf.
In principle the same applies when calling fgets. But there's more to it than that...
messages_array holds pointers to string literals (aka text strings). In C string literals can't be modified. Trying to modify a constant string in C results in undefined behavior.
And that's exactly what fgets will do. So you have a problem. To solve it, you need to turn messages_array into something that allows the strings to be modified.
There are a number of different ways to do that. Here is one:
#define MAX_SIZE 100

char messages_array[9][MAX_SIZE] = {"this mesage has not yet been set", .....};

Now messages_array isn't pointers to string literals. Now it can actual hold the real string values. It's initialized as copies of string literals but once initialized, messages_array holds it's own modifiable strings.
Disclaimer
There may be other problems in your code. I just focused on this problem.
For instance I'm pretty sure sizeof(new_message) is not doing what you expect. Try:
printf("%zu\n", sizeof(new_message));

